# Button BackgroundImage Property

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, button

I am trying to write an application on Windows Mobile but I am experiencing a problem.

I want to draw a picture of arrows on the button but I do not know how to do this.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a custom control. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229655.aspx) for an example. You can draw the icon using Graphics.DrawImage function.